# Selecting rows with partial match/mismatch in 2 columns

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I am looking how to select rows in R which have partial matches or mismatches in two columns. My dataset (as an example) looks like this:

```
df = data.frame(plot1 = c("ABX_15", "BHE_05", "ABX_15"), 
                plot2 = c("AB6_15", "JKS_05", "JKS_05"),
                value = c(0.4, 0.45, 0.34))
```

I want to create subsets containing only "matched" pairs of `plot1` and `plot2` for `_05` and `_15`. So that would be either the first row or the second row in the example. I also need to select only rows which have a missmatch in `plot1` and `plot2`, that would be row number three. Match an missmatch refer only to the second part of the plot name.

I've found solutions for partial selecting and for selecting certain rows according to columns but I could not combine both.

I am expecting 3 subsets of the dataset: One with matching `_05` another with matching `_15` and one with missmatches.

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: I am expecting 3 subsets of the dataset: One with matching _05 another with matching _15 and one with missmatches

Comment: @NR Don't post additional info in the comments, please use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37206518/edit) next time to update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is using `sub` to strip everything before (and including) the underscore from the two variables and then compare those `sub` statements with `==` to create a logical index vector:

```
idx <- sub('.*\\_', '', df$plot1) == sub('.*\\_', '', df$plot2)
```

Now you can subset `df` with that vector. `df[idx,]` gives:

```
   plot1  plot2 value
1 ABX_15 AB6_15  0.40
2 BHE_05 JKS_05  0.45
```

To get the mismatches, you can use `df[!idx,]`:

```
   plot1  plot2 value
3 ABX_15 JKS_05  0.34
```

---

Per the update of your requirements, you can create indexes for matching on `15` or `05` as follows:

```
idx15 <- sub('.*\\_', '', df$plot1) == '15' & sub('.*\\_', '', df$plot2) == '15'
idx05 <- sub('.*\\_', '', df$plot1) == '05' & sub('.*\\_', '', df$plot2) == '05'
```

These can then be used to subset `df` as shown above (e.g. `df[idx15,]`). To get the mismatches: `df[!idx05 & !idx15,]` (or use the method from above).

Comment: Thak's for your update - I just answered the question of the comment. The adjustment of your solution was not a problem. I did it slightly different but it seems to work also: `id05 <- sub('.*\\_05', '', df$plot1) == sub('.*\\_05', '', df$plot2)`. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fist spilt the names by the pattern `_`. I'm using here the function `str_split` from the `stringr` package. The result is a list. You can extract now the second part of the name. After unlisting you can add the result to your dataframe `df`:

```
df$p1 <- unlist(lapply(str_split(df$plot1, "_"), "[", 2))
df$p2 <- unlist(lapply(str_split(df$plot2, "_"), "[", 2))
```

For a base R solution you can use `strspilt` function instead. Note that you have to make a character vector out of it.

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$plot1), "_"), "[", 2))
```

and the result:

```
df[df$p1 == df$p2, ]
   plot1  plot2 value p1 p2
1 ABX_15 AB6_15  0.40 15 15
2 BHE_05 JKS_05  0.45 05 05
```

For the mismatch use:

```
df[df$p1 != df$p2, ]
   plot1  plot2 value p1 p2
3 ABX_15 JKS_05  0.34 05 15
```